# How to install macvim on OS X 10.7 Lion from its .tbz package?

Tags: mac, gvim, macvim

I got a .tbz file from http://code.google.com/p/macvim/

I am a new Mac User. And i would like to use macvim for my development.

How can I upzip this file and make installation for that .tbz file?

One follow up question is that MacVim-snapshot-64....What does snapshot actually mean in this file?

Answer (score 2):

I just had a look and it seems that the MacVim.app is compressed inside that file, so installing it won't be tricky at all - just drag to the Applications folder.

You'll use `tar` at the Terminal prompt to unzip it, or a GUI tool like [BetterZip](http://macitbetter.com/) (not free, but it's what I use), which also opens these files.

A snapshot is an unstable release, meaning that it can have bugs in it and is not fully tested for the platform. On some projects, a snapshot can be released as frequently as every day.